# jstree lazy load specific nodes and select those

Tags: jquery, jstree, jstree-search

I have a `jstree` where only root nodes are loaded and children are loaded as the root is expanded. 
Now I have list of Ids of nodes to be selected but those nodes are not loaded yet. 
I want to lazy load & then check those specific nodes.

One possible way could be to `open_all` and when all the nodes are loaded then iterate and select the required nodes.

What else could I do to achieve this functionality?